# C# Converting image, audio and video to and from byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, directx

I'm working on a C# WinForms project in which I have to convert the following to byte arrays and then write to a binary file using `FileStream` and `BinaryWriter`:

```
System.Drawing.Image image
Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Audio audio 
Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video video
```

Then I must read them from a binary file using `FileStream` and `BinaryReader` and convert them back into the above file types.

Here's the code for converting them to byte arrays prior to writing them to binary:

```
    public byte[] Image2Bytes(Image imgImage2Convert)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imgImage2Convert.Save(ms, imgImage2Convert.RawFormat);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public byte[] Audio2Bytes(Audio audAudio2Convert)
    {
        var bytes = default(byte[]);

        using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memstream);
            var buffer = new byte[512];
            var bytesRead = default(int);
            while ((bytesRead = reader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                memstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytes = memstream.ToArray();
            return bytes;
        }
    }

    public byte[] Video2Bytes(Video vidVideo2Convert)
    {
        var bytes = default(byte[]);

        using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memstream);
            var buffer = new byte[512];
            var bytesRead = default(int);
            while ((bytesRead = reader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                memstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            bytes = memstream.ToArray();
            return bytes;
        }
    }
```

And here are the methods for converting them back into their original image, audio and video files:

```
    public Image Bytes2Image(byte[] bytBytes2Convert)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytBytes2Convert, 0, bytBytes2Convert.Length);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return returnImage;
    }

    public Audio Bytes2Audio(byte[] bytBytes2Convert)
    {
        string strTempFile = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\MyTempFile.mp3";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(strTempFile, bytBytes2Convert);
        Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Audio audConvertedAudio = Audio.FromFile(strTempFile);
        DeleteTempFile(strTempFile);

        return audConvertedAudio;
    }

    public Video Bytes2Video(byte[] bytBytes2Convert)
    {
        string strTempFile = Path.GetTempPath() + "MyTempFile.wmv";
        File.WriteAllBytes(strTempFile, bytBytes2Convert);
        Video vidConvertedVideo = Video.FromFile(strTempFile);
        DeleteTempFile(strTempFile);

        return vidConvertedVideo;
    }
```

Here are three lines of code to show how I'm writing them to binary:

```
bw.Write(GameInfo.bytTSImage);
bw.Write(GameInfo.bytTSAudio);
bw.Write(GameInfo.bytTSVideo);
```

And here are three lines of code to demonstrate how I'm trying to read them from binary:

```
    clsProjInfo.bytTSImage = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
    clsProjInfo.bytTSAudio = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
    clsProjInfo.bytTSVideo = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
```

The error occurs the first time I try to convert a byte array back into audio using `public Audio Bytes2Audio(byte[] bytBytes2Convert)`:

> The error is "System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream."

This error occurs on a line where I try to read an integer value with `ReadInt32();`

Am I converting the files to byte array correctly? That's the first thing I suspect I'm doing wrong. Or is `br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length)` a bad way to read from binary?

Here's a little more info:

First I read a string, then an integer, then a byte array, all in the order shown below:

```
        clsProjInfo.strCreationDate = br.ReadString();
        clsProjInfo.intTSMediaType = br.ReadInt32();
        clsProjInfo.bytTSImage = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
```

Then, after reading the byte array (clsProjInfo.bytTSImage), I next try to read second integer:

```
        clsProjInfo.intTSMediaType = br.ReadInt32();
```

And it's when I try to read that second integer that I get the error "System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream." It looks to me like my BinaryReader (br) doesn't know that it should be done reading that byte array and it should read the second integer next. If that's the case, is there something better I can use to map out the length of the byte array instead of "br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);"

That last line of code "clsProjInfo.intTSMediaType = br.ReadInt32();" keeps reading a zero when it should be reading a 1. I'm guessing the byte array is not being fully read before reading the second integer.

Comment: `memstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` should be `memstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, manman. I just updated the question with more info about my situation.

Comment: What are you trying to read? You're storing the whole video / image / audio without storing any string or creation date and then try to read them separately? `br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length)` reads the whole stream, I kinda expected you get an error on that line.

Comment: Well, if "(int)br.BaseStream.Length" reads the whole stream, how can I read the audio from beginning to its end and then read whatever follows without the reader spilling over?

Comment: How do you store those bytes? Need more info on the structure that you're storing them, like if you're storing several media types, image / video / audio, in one file or they are in separate files and if you only store the data or if you add more info to it. BTW you can always get the media type and creation date from file attribute and file content.

Comment: Never mind, I just figured out what to do. Since I'm writing the byte array to a file, may as well write its length first, then do "byte[] SomeBytes = binaryreader.ReadBytes(SomeBytes.Length);".